# Run js function once when fired more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Div that uses jQuery to load a file/contents with a javascript function..

```
function DoWork() {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Let's say the user can reload the Div and pull the same file/contents with the same js function DoWork(). The problem is, when the file is reloaded, the previous loaded function DoWork() is still running. How can I kill the previous fired DoWork() and restart it?

Comment: What do you mean by "reload the div"? Is this handled via an event handler? If so, why not just unbind the handler once it's fired? (or use something like jQuery's `once`)

Comment: easiest to put the original function declaration in a conditional  `if(typeof DoWork === 'undefined'){ function DoWork(){ ... } }` so it only is loaded if it's not already detected.

Comment: Is there an interval running in `DoWork`?  What is the usage model?  Why does it take a long time to run?

Comment: @DanielMendel I think putting function declarations in a condition is frowned upon.

Comment: I mean I pull the html of an external php file into the DIV using jquery

Comment: You need to include more code or be more clear. Are you saying that you call `DoWork()` twice, and it loads the same div twice? Or is `DoWork()` defined inside a div that is loaded dynamically and then runs twice?

Comment: @bhamlin - Yes. DoWork() is called twice and it is loaded in the same div twice because the external php that is called loads the function DoWork(). Therefore it is repeating the function

Comment: @alex that's context dependant but you're right -- also, that approach means the global namespace is being polluted by `DoWork`.  Really it should be done from inside the function and things shouldn't be defined globally `function(){ if(!window.mynamespace.didWork){ ... }}` but that seems like a too-complicated answer for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded, which means only one thing can be executing at a given moment.  If `DoWork` is already "running" it's either a) blocking all other JS code, and you have no choice but to let it finish since you have no way to execute any interruption code until it finishes on its own, or b) `DoWork` is scheduled to fire off on an interval via `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

If it's the latter case, `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` return an ID.  Store that ID somewhere and call `clearTimeout(doWork_timeout_id)` or `clearInterval(doWork_interval_id)` according to how you started it.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a simple function that use: setTimeout and then each call to DoWork will call first to: clearTimeout. I don't really like this solution because you will waste CPU on setTimeout.
So another option will be to use web worker in DoWork (It will do lots of other good things for you in case you are working with big data as it's running in another thread) - then you get an option to send 'stop' message each time you start the work of DoWork().

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ajax to load the div's contents? if so, the better way is as follows:

```
var doWorkAjax=null;
function DoWork(){
    if (doWorkAjax) doWorkAjax.abort(); 
    doWorkAjax = $.ajax(url, data, function(result){
        ....
        doWorkAjax=null;
    });
}
```

Comment: yes I am using AJAX to load the php file in the Div which contains js function DoWork()